# css animation 'stutters' on first call, but subsequent calls are smooth as butter

Tags: css, performance, animation

I am simply adding a class with to a div with four images (50x50) in it on a button click. The class calls a css animation that translates the div from the left to the center of page. The div is hidden because the page body is set to overflow hidden.

No other JavaScript code is being executed after the class is added.

The first time it is called it 'stutters' and has choppy framerate, but pressing the button that calls it again it animates very smoothly.

What is going on?

**note: I am working on kiosk software that uses Chromium Embedded Framework on a AMD duel core 1.5ghz processor. It works fine on my quad core 1.8 laptop, but choppy on our machine **

is the selector and id being cached so the browser doesn't have to search for it again?

Comment: Is the choppy behaviour observable on all browsers?

Comment: Can you post some code or a jsfiddle for reference.

Comment: I am working on kiosk software that uses Chromium Embedded Framework on a AMD duel core 1.5ghz processor. It works fine on my quad core 1.8 laptop, but choppy on our machine

Comment: Is there a possibility to offload the animation to the kiosks GPU?
adding "-webkit-transform : translateZ(0);" to your animation will do this.

Comment: Doesn't work because we have gpu acceleration turned off because with it on it's worse. The gpu isn't very high performance.  I guess I'm surprised that the 1.5 duel core doesn't cut it.

Comment: But why would the animation be choppy the first time , but immediate subsequent calls are very smooth?